# How to Display a Keyboard in detailView of splitView Controller in Ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on ipad Application. In my app, i'm using Split View. Now, i want to show the keyboard in only detailView Window. I have googled, but i can't get the solution to my problem. Please give me solution if anyone have worked out similar to this concept

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make your custom keyboard, as with default keyboard its not possible

Comment: in textfield delegate methods check with bool condition to open up the keyboard

Comment: how much and what's Control in your detailsView of splitView.?

Comment: In textField delegate call textField resignFirstResponder and animate and show your own custom view with keys in it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the keyboard to appdelegate or self.view add to detailviewcontroller.view.It will fix the issue.